# FragmentPagerAdapter vs FragmentStatePager. what is the real difference

Tags: android

what is the real difference between this two type of adapter ?
i ve used many times FragmentPagerAdapter with fragment-page. i see that it keep in memory also the previous and the next fragment page. I think that FragmentStatePager doesnt do this. But now i ve used FragmentStatePager and i've noticed the same thing.